# Callback for Async.Map Not Working

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm relatively new to callbacks and have been unsuccessful in getting the following code to work. I have used the async.map function to return the data from each web call to its respective page. However, my `console.log(return)` is returning `[ , undefined]` even though the `console.log(data)` prior to the `callback(data)` is returning the web page's html. Here's my code:

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    page, chap, ot,
    async = require("async");

ot = fs.open('ot.txt', 'w');        
page = "test";
chap = 2;

function getData(url, callback) {
  var data = "";
  var options = {
    host: "rs.au.com",
    port: 80
  }
  options.path = url;
  console.log("request sent to: http://" + options.host + options.path);
  var req = http.request(options, function(res) { 
    console.log("Response received " + res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(e) {
        console.log(data);
        callback(e, data);
    });
  }).end();
}   

function main() {
  var pathArr = [];
  for ( var i = 1; i <= chap; i++ ) {
    pathArr[i] = "/".concat(page, "/", i, ".html");
  }
  async.map(pathArr, getData, function(err, result) {
    console.log("The result is :" + result);
  });
}

main();
```

Could anyone please point out why my code is not working and how I can correct it?

Much appreciated!

**EDIT:** After Brandon Tilley's response I amended the callback function from `callback(data)` to `callback(e, data)`, however I'm getting no response now from the last `console.log` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Async library assumes your callbacks adhere to the standard Node.js callback signature, which is `callback(err, others...)`. Since you are passing `data` as the first argument, Async assumes it's an error. You should use `callback(e, data)` instead (since `e` will be `null` in the case of no errors).

**[Update]**

The other problem is that your array is not correct. Since `i` starts at 1 and goes up to `chap`, `pathArr[0]` is undefined. Change:

```
pathArr[i] = "/".concat(page, "/", i, ".html");
```

to

```
pathArr[i-1] = "/".concat(page, "/", i, ".html");
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon for your reply! Unfortunately I have tried your solution, however, I don't get any array output from the `console.log(result)` command? I've edited my code above to reflect the new change.